# WebDriver: How to optimize a wait statement inside try catch

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

there is a web element which comes randomly and I handled it using try catch using a wait statement in both try as well as catch. However the code is working perfectly fine, I just need to know if there is a way to optimize it in order to decrease the execution time as it is taking too long to execute?

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Please add your code, so that we may understand the way you are handling it and what is leading to a delay.

Comment: Not enough information, show us your code.